# Swift Async Call in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uitextview

What is the best way to **async call** to load a **UIImage to a textView** as a NSTextAttachment in a tableView? So far this is working very badly.

I am using a URL string to load a single image inside multiple tableView cells.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    //Transform Data From ^ to load at the bottom
    tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);
    cell?.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);
    cell?.accessoryView?.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);

    let username = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UITextView
    username.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].username

    let message = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UITextView
    //message.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].message // delete later

    var test = messageArray[indexPath.row].uploadedPhotoUrl
    print(test ?? String.self)

    if(test != ""){
        // create an NSMutableAttributedString that we'll append everything to
        let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")

        // create our NSTextAttachment
        let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: messageArray[indexPath.row].uploadedPhotoUrl)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? String())
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                image1Attachment.image = image

                //calculate new size.  (-20 because I want to have a litle space on the right of picture)
                let newImageWidth = (message.bounds.size.width - 20 )

                //resize this
                image1Attachment.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: newImageWidth, height: 200)

                // wrap the attachment in its own attributed string so we can append it
                let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)

                // add the NSTextAttachment wrapper to our full string, then add some more text.
                fullString.append(image1String)
                fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: message.text))

                // draw the result in a label
                message.attributedText = fullString

                //message.textStorage.insert(image1String, at: message.selectedRange.location)

                message.textColor = .white

                test = ""
            })
        }).resume()
    }else {
        message.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].message
    }

    let timeStamp = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    timeStamp.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].timeStamp

    let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UIImageView
    imageView.image = nil
    let urlString = messageArray[indexPath.row].photoUrl
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    //Load profile image(on cell) with URL & Alamofire Library
    let downloadURL = NSURL(string: urlString!)
    imageView.af_setImage(withURL: downloadURL! as URL)

    return cell!
}
```

Images are still lagging when index is scrolling(appearing and disappearing)  and are also not loading completely

[image]

Comment: Considering there is no code for the table view cell in your `cellForRowAt`, it's no wonder it's not working.

Comment: I didnt post the entire problem just what im trying to accomplish

Comment: "working badly" isn't a helpful description. Please [edit] your question with specific details about what exact issues you are having with your posted code.

Comment: i have updated.

Comment: This is very slow because you are calling each image at a time while loading the tableview.

Comment: How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading an image at a time while the tableviewcell is scrolling. There is some time to call the service and then wait for the response to be returned, thus affecting the scrolling although it is on another thread.

You can try calling the images in batches of maybe 10 or 20 at a time.

Comment: how do i call them in batches?

Answer (score -1):

**TL/DR:**
Learn to write better code.

For starters, there's no way `tableView(:cellForRowAt:)` can accomplish all that work in under 16 milliseconds. I think you should reconsider your app structure and architecture for starters. It would serve your app better to abstract the networking calls to an API that can run on a background thread(s).

One way would be to abstract away a lot of the implementation to an`OperationQueue` [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift) has a couple tutorials on how this works. This particular one was written for Swift 1.2, however the principles for `Operation` are there.